# How to not show pre-defined relationship types when double-clicking a node in neo4j Browser

Tags: neo4j

I have defined several relationship types between several nodes having a common label. Conceptually, those relationship types can be grouped in two different domains. The problem I am facing is that when navigating through the model in the Browser by double-clicking the nodes, all relationship types show up making it confusing are there are kind of two conceptual domains overlapping. Is there a way to assign relationship types to domains and then instruct the browser to show only relationships of one specific doman when double-clicking a node?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, I think I know what you mean.  It depends on your version, but I believe if you have the latest (2.2.x) then you can unselect the "Auto-complete" in the lower right of your query graph visualization panes.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but that actually does not solve the problem. The auto-complete seems to work adding result elements to a query you explicitly execute. In my case I just start showing only the nodes I am interested in without any relationship. Then when I double-click a node an implicit query is triggered by the Browser to show ALL relationships for that node. I would like to define some grouping rule to only show some relationship types on double-click.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  I don't think something like that is currently possible.  I think you'd need to craft cypher queries to return just the nodes and relationships that you want to see

Comment: That's planned for a future release of Neo4j, right now it is not possible to change that without changing the neo4j-browser javascript.